Is there a contemporary "Christian" theology which claims Jesus was God only and not really man?
There are a multiplicity of contemporary claims regarding Jesus made by folks who refer to themselves as Christian.

Jesus was and is both God and man.

Jesus was and is only man

Jesus was an angel, became a man, and is an angel again.  (Or was and is both.)

Jesus was a man and now is God.


These are, perhaps, not all of the options and certainly not all of the nuances.  What I have not come across is a contemporary claim that Jesus was God only and not really man at all.  Docetism is one form of the sort of thing I am referring to but I am unaware if Docetism is still alive under the umbrella of claimed Christianity:

In the history of Christianity, docetism (from the Koinē Greek: δοκεῖν/δόκησις dokeĩn "to seem", dókēsis "apparition, phantom"1) was the doctrine that the phenomenon of Jesus, his historical and bodily existence, and above all the human form of Jesus, was mere semblance without any true reality.[3][4] Broadly it is taken as the belief that Jesus only seemed to be human, and that his human form was an illusion. - Wikipedia

I have seen articles describing "docetic christianity" wherein the importance of being led of the Spirit becomes so magnified that human responsibility to any sort of biblical hermeneutic disappears:

On this view, it becomes unimportant whether Jesus lived or died according to the Gospel records. What matters is the ethical and existential message of the stories about him; how the story affects my understanding of myself.

This begins to sound like what I have seen described as Christian Atheism in practice, but theologically cannot be since Christian Atheism denies the existence of God:
Are there any contemporary denominations who claim to be Christian and whose theology holds that Jesus was God only and not really human?

Wikipedia claims that docetism largely died out in the first millennia.  A quick search for modern counterparts showed Mennonites as possibly leaning that way.  The reason for that is they supposedly say that Christ didn't receive his humanity from Mary but he passed through her as "water through a pipe" bringing nothing along from her.  More here: https://anabaptistworld.org/menno-got-wrong-difference-makes/

@Aleph-Gimel That is a very insightful article relevant to this Q, it's a keeper for me.  Thanks for sharing, maybe you want to write an answer based on it?  Some Charismatics I know are so focused on the Holy Spirit work (thus Jesus's divine nature) that they neglect the perfected human nature that Christ also brings via his "incarnated flesh" (to contrast with Menno's "celestial flesh") to renew our mind.  "So Menno holds to the high ideals of Christ while also undercutting our ability to live by those ideals. .... God had to bypass our flesh in order to bring salvation."

@Aleph-Gimel Good find.  The more extreme Mennonites might be as close as we'll find even though they technically hold Jesus as human, just not inherited humanity.
